# Installed BS4 but get traceback "ImportError: No module named bs4" when I run python script from macos high sierra

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I’m trying to run a python script with BS4 on macos high sierra.

I ran both of these commands successfully.

```
pip3 install BeautifulSoup4
pip3 install requests
```

I tried to run this python script

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(ivwTest.html)
for script in soup(["script", "style"]):
    script.decompose()
strips = list(soup.stripped_strings)
print(strips[:5])
```

I got this traceback

```
erics-iMac:pythonPractice eric$ python aPythonScript.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "aPythonScript.py", line 3, in <module>
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
ImportError: No module named bs4
erics-iMac:pythonPractice eric$
```

I’m not using a python virtual environment.

Any ideas what’s going on?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: There might be different versions of Python on your computer. Are you sure `pip3` installs the libraries for the same Python version you call with `python`?

Comment: Is it that in `pip3 install BeautifulSoup4` there are uppercase letters? From [Pypi.org](https://pypi.org/project/beautifulsoup4/) all letters are lowercase .

Comment: Try `python3 aPythonScript.py`. If that doesn't work, try installing bs4 again with the best practice method: `python3 -m pip install beautifulsoup4`